# How to hide the scrollbar?

Tags: quill

I use Quill, and I use a scrollbar plug-in in it, but the original scrollbar of Quill still exists. That's no effect with `overflow: hidden`. How can I hide it?

[Two overlapping scrollbars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkDsy.png)

Comment: Can you post a CodePen or JSFiddle? overflow: hidden; works for me.

Comment: @jhchen                                                                                                       I just put "overflow:hidden" in div's style:                                                   '<div id="postContent" style="overflow:hidden">
</div>'                                                                                                     'var editor = new Quill('#postContent', {
      modules: {
        toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
      },
      theme: 'snow'
    });'

Comment: If you inspect #postContent you will see it does not have any scrollbars--one of its children does. The overflow: hidden needs to go there.

Comment: That is ok,thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty hard solve the issue without actually seeing the code but here's what worked for me.

```
.ql-container, .ql-editor{
  height: auto;
}
```

That's it, now the quill scroll bar should disappear and in absence of a secondary scrollbar attached, the .ql-container should auto grow fitting the content.